# Join two tables based on one column for multiple values from second table

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have table `store_profile` like this

```
id Storename        Storetype        address
1  Samsung Store    Electronics      Delhi
2  Levi             Clothing         Mumbai
3  Soni             Electronics      Bangalore
```

and second table `Offers`:

```
id Store_id         offer           price
1  Samsung Store    flat 30% off     20000
2  Levi             Exchange         5000
3  Samsung Store    Exchange offer   40000
```

I want to get all the store details from `store_profile` for particular type, say Electronics, and for each store their offers in single row, not repeated as I am getting from this syntax in json.

Mysql query is -:

```
SELECT 
    *, Offers.Store_id
FROM 
    Store_profile 
INNER JOIN
    Offers ON Store_profile.Storename = Offers.Store_id 
           AND Store_profile.Storetype LIKE '%Electronics%'
```

Here is my php code

```
$sql ="SELECT * , Offers.Store_id FROM Store_profile INNER JOIN Offers ON Store_profile.Storename = Offers.Store_id AND Store_profile.Storetype like '%Electronics%' LIMIT 0 , 300 ";
$r = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

$result = array();

 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r)){

   array_push($result,array(

        'Store_Name'=>$row['Storename'],
        'Store_address'=>$row['address'],
        'Offer_Title'=>$row['offer'],
        'MRP_Price'=>$row['price'],

 ));

}


echo json_encode(array('result'=>$result));

mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: Edit your question and show the output you would like to get from the database.

Comment: i want to get json like this result["Storename"-Samsung Store,Store_address - Delhi,Offer[Offer_Title-Flat 30% Off,MRP_Price20000,Offer_Title-Exchange offer,MRP_Price40000 ]]